# Displaying AJAX results into a table

Tags: html, json, ajax

folks, I have some AJAX code that queries a Google Calendar and brings in the current months activities via a results list variable called myList.

The code works fine however now I'm trying to get the data to display properly inside a table. However, the HTML to call the results from the ajax script uses the ID inside either a DIV or P HTML tag which does not display correctly in the table but rather on top of the intended table. (See Screen Shot)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaal5.png)

I thought by putting the code along with the ID for the output results into the DIV tag is would display the results including the opening and closing tags for TR and TD. Take a look:

```js
<div class="container scroll">
  <table class="table isSearch" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-heads ">
        <th class="head-item mbr-fonts-style display-7">
          EVENT TITLE
        </th>
        <th class="head-item mbr-fonts-style display-7">
          DATE &amp; TIME
        </th>
        <th class="head-item mbr-fonts-style display-7">
          DETAILS
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <div id="myList"></div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        //Jquery's ajax request
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '<% str_getDate %>',

          dataType: 'json',
          async: true
        })
          .done(function(data) {
            //once we get a successful response this callback function
            //gets fired, and "data" contains the parsed JSON file.

            //here we iterate over the object array
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
              //I do this to later format these timestamps
              //set options for date.toLocaleDateString() function

              var options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };

              let start = new Date(item.start.dateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

              let end = new Date(item.end.dateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

              let end_splt = end.split(',');

              //append data to the list.

              if (item.status != 'cancelled') {
                $('#myList').append(`

                                                    <tr><td class='body-item mbr-fonts-style display-7'>${
                                                      item.summary
                                                    }</td><td class='body-item mbr-fonts-style display-7'>${start} - ${
                  end_splt[1]
                }</td><td class='body-item mbr-fonts-style display-7'>${item.description}</td></tr>

                                                    `);
              }
            });
          })
          .fail(function(e) {
            error(e);
          });

        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
      </script>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Interesting, The code you provided did work however sometimes when the page is loaded the table data is in the table Bootstrap container and sometimes it's not. Here is a link to the page. https://eaa309.club/calendar.asp

Whenever the table didn't load within the container the very first row indicates no data to be displayed. Other times when I refresh the page it does load correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sr9R.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1VfM.png)

By the way I have tried to paste my code intot he post but it didnt like that, so I have included a screen shot (YUCK) Sorry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69HdN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `div` from the table body (if you can). And, move the script out of there as well (if you can). Either way, you can append to the `tbody` directly, like this.

```
            $('table.isSearch tbody').append(`
```

Comment: Bitwise was wondering if you could help me with this. Your revised code works but I am having problems with the consistency of it compiling correctly on the page. I am using Mobirise to create a the front end. The page template I am using allows me to create a table enter data into it and the UI will allow users to search the data that i manually entered into the various cells. My initial thought was lets make the table dynamic by grabbing events out on the google calendar using the API (JSON) and generating the cells and rows dynamically. When the page compiles the calendar data displays

Comment: ... but most of the time its not displaying as data that is used in the bootstrap table, therefor the table indicates "NO DATA AVAILABLE IN TABLE" Anyway here is the URL? to see what I mean. You'll notice that when you see NO DATA AVAILABLE IN TABLE then the search button doesn't find anything even when data is there on the page, and the number of records is incorrect even know the data is there. Very random. https://eaa309.club/calendar.asp

Comment: When you first go to the page it actually may work,(i just tried and it did) But try hitting refresh.. you'll see what I mean.